# OpenMP is not doing actual parallelism when using GCC

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, openmp

I am running Ubuntu 12 on Virtual box and I am using GCC to compile this simple C program that has simple OpenMp pragmas :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define MAX 10000000000
void main()
{
    unsigned long long i,j,k,l;
    int threadnumber;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(i,j,k,l)
    {
        threadnumber = omp_get_thread_num();
        if(threadnumber == 0)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < (MAX / 4); i++)
                ;
        }
        else if(threadnumber == 1)
        {
            for(j = (MAX / 4); j < (MAX / 2); j++)
                ;
        }
        else if(threadnumber == 2)
        {
            for(k = (MAX / 2); k < (3 * (MAX / 4));k++)
                ;
        }
        else
        {
            for(l = (3 * (MAX / 4)); l < MAX; l++)
                ;
        }
    }
}
```

My Processor is an Intel Core i5 one.
The program is indeed working in parallel (verified through adding some printf()s) , I have set the environment variable(OMP_NUM_THREADS) to 4.
The problem is that code is taking much time than this one which is not parallel :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000000000
void main()
{
    unsigned long long i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        ;
}
```

I have also tried to add `clock()` calls before and after the loop in both versions and I am getting a higher time in the parallel version.
I have also tried to measure the time using : time `./a.out` and I am getting (in the parallel version only) different "real" time than what is returned by `clock()` !

I have compiled both codes on visual studio and here are the results :

1. In Debug mode : both codes are given nearly equal times and that time is near to what is given by GCC.
2. In Release mode : Both codes are faster and the parallel one shows a great improvement in time.
   The Problem in a nutshell :
3. I want to run the program in parallel with that same efficiency as in the release version of visual studio's compiler.
   2) Is there a parameter or option that I should pass to GCC other than the `"-fopenmp"` to make it build a release version exactly like visual studio.
   3) I want to know if it is an Ubuntu thing problem or a GCC one or WHAT ???

P.S : I have tried running the same procedure on an Ubuntu with wubi installation and on an Ubuntu as a standalone OS (on an ext4 File System) and on the same platform and I am getting the same results.

Comment: In Linux, `clock()` measures CPU time. It doesn't measure real time.

Comment: There are several questions here already that ask about "why is my non parallel version faster". In your case with this snippet, doing nothing  sequentially will probably be faster than the overhead of doing nothing in parallel.

Comment: Please guys focus on the main issue :
It is running extremely faster when compiled on Visual studio in Release mode but this is not the case with GCC !

Comment: @Mysticial : Sorry, I forgot to say thanks :-)
That was an important point to take care of !
But does that mean that clock() in windows measures real time ?
Another question : How to measure real time in linux in some parts only of the program not on the whole program (like by using : time ./a.out) ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really don't understand why every new OpenMP-related question here on SO contains code that uses `clock()` to (wrongly) measure wall-clock execution time, provided that OpenMP has a portable high resolution timer, available via a call to `omp_get_wtime()`?

First, using shared variables as loop counters inside a parallel region is a **terrible terrible idea**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259286/1374437) is why, although you have a Nehalem or later microarchitecture based CPU which makes this less of a problem.

Second, Visual Studio applies different optimisation levels in Debug and Release configurations. In debug mode optimisation is disabled (`/Od`) while in release mode optimisation for speed is enabled (`/O2`). You say that in debug mode VS code runs as fast as the GCC code. This probably means that you run GCC with its default optimisation level of no optimisation. Compile with `-O2` or even with `-O3` to get code on par with what VS generates in release mode.

Third, you are running Ubuntu inside a virtual machine. How many CPUs does the virtual machine has access to?

Fourth, why are you reimplementing the OpenMP parallel `for` worksharing directive?

Comment: I have tried omp parallel for but it didn't also come with a change in time so I thought that it may not be very effective :-) Thanks a lot for the reply !

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of drawing conclusions from such simple measurements. An empty loop as you have it here should be most modern compilers be just optimized out completely. Such optimizations may here be a bit hindered by your `OMP` pragma. But this really has nothing to do with parallelism or not.